# cordova callback returns null

Tags: java, android, cordova

I am making a [simple wrapper for Pebble android SDK in cordova](https://github.com/konsumer/phonegap-pebble). I am starting simple with 2 methods: `isWatchConnected` & `getWatchFWVersion`.

I made a [tester cordova project](https://github.com/konsumer/testpebble) complete with the tester code. Everything builds fine.

When I play with it in the Chrome "Inspect Devices" console, Pebble object looks ok.

If I run these (in console):

```
Pebble.getWatchFWVersion(function(v){ console.log(v); });
Pebble.isWatchConnected(function(v){ console.log(v); });
```

I expect to get a JSON object or 1/0, and I just get null for both.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, first arg is error!  it works ok, like this:

```
Pebble.getWatchFWVersion(function(er, v){ console.log(v); });
```